# Ionic as Bootstrap alternative for Laravel?

Tags: html, laravel, ionic-framework, frameworks, hybrid

I have to create a application with 1). a webinterface and 2). an ios/android app. I will use Laravel as backend framework.

Now I can use Laravel for the webinterface and the API, and Ionic for the app (that communicates with the Laravel API).
The "*problem*" is: I have to create 2 webinterfaces... (the Laravel online webinterface AND the Ionic webinterface (= offline in a ios/android WebView)).

Thats why my question is: can I run Ionic (or another alternative) as frontend framework in my Laravel? So I can run this Ionic interface in my app webview? I need the same functionalities, like camera, GPS, push, etc. as the "normal" Ionic.
Or is there an alternative with the same look and feel as Ionic, but 100% online? So I can run my webapplication in a WebView container.

Comment: i think ionic should be your front end for web also, meaning you wouldnt have a laravel front end. but i dont know. This question will likely be closed because it isn't a programming question btw.

Comment: Use Ionic for both web and app. If they are too different, create two projects that uses an third project containing shared scaffolding as services, models and components. Then Laravel exists only as an API, using Laravel Passport to authenticate.